# Does $state.go from my current state to current state fires relevant events?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angular-ui-router, state

Suppose that I am in state A, and inside this state I have a button with `ng-click` like so:

```
$scope.go = function() {
    $state.go("A");
}
```

I have a question that are these events: `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` are fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` would not be fired in your example.

Here is plunker for you to check this out. http://plnkr.co/edit/MkdO0yuWh6SbZ3mGlecj?p=preview

If you want to fire these events, please specify some additional params

```
$scope.go = function() {
    $state.go("A", {}, {reload: true});
}
```

Also state.go() is a wrapper for state.transitionTo() 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blame/legacy/src/state.js#L910-L929

Hope it helps you to understand the basics.